# How to use JavaScript in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have added Javascript kernel to Google Colab using following commands:

```
!npm install -g --unsafe-perm ijavascript zeromq
!ijsinstall --install=global
!jupyter-kernelspec list
```

Now I want to code using JavaScript. How can I change the kernel?

Comment: IJavascript isn't supported in Colab.

Comment: It is now supported, see https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/13

Answer (score 21):

I make a simplified version from @obenjiro 's answer. And make it into 2 shortened URLs (choose one).

- [bit.ly/colabjs](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/korakot/22abd6eccac229e9cb9a027b088b50d6/notebook.ipynb)

You go there.

- Select `Copy to Drive` to make it your own.
- Run the first cell.
- Reload the page
- Skip the first cell.
- Run the second cell, then run any JavaScript codes you want.

Comment: for a detailed walkthrough, also see https://dev.to/obenjiro/silence-of-the-fans-part-1-javascript-quickstart-5f3m

Comment: You should definitely join Tensorflow_js_EN community in telegram. This method may not work but one member of the community made another workaround

With JUPNODE

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_Gmt-q8TCpV8q7lDmO3vikHrC9r8-0jY?usp=sharing

Answer (score 9):

After inserting `%%javascript` there will only be JavaScript code.

Comment: how to assign javascript calculated data to python variables

Comment: While not what the OP was asking for, this will technically work. However, each cell is sandboxed and you cannot directly receive output or (easily) share Javascript runtime context between cells. As a workaround, see here for information on passing Javascript values back into Python: https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-pass-variables-from-javascript-to-python-in-jupyter-notebook/

Answer (score 4):

**NEW ANSWER**

There is a project called JupNode that allows you to do that (https://github.com/Graphnull/jupnode)

Here's an example
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_Gmt-q8TCpV8q7lDmO3vikHrC9r8-0jY?usp=sharing

**OLD ANSWER**

I made a simple to bootstrap template that allows you to run TensroflowJS on Google Colab, install modules in notebook, and run long running async code. Just open

> tinyurl.com/tf-js-colab

and you ready to go! :)

For detailed walkthrough
https://dev.to/obenjiro/silence-of-the-fans-part-1-javascript-quickstart-5f3m

Comment: As of August 2023, it doesn't appear that this approach is working any more. While it is possible to follow the instructions above and install the Node.js javascript kernel on Colab and even change the kernel type in the UI, the Colab notebook will not connect to the runtime.

I spent a good amount of time trying to debug it with no success. I tried pinning the npm and ijavascript (5.0.20) versions to those used back in the era when it was working, but the installation fails due to what appears to be version skew between the Node runtime (14.16.0) and Zeromq 4.6.0 (prebuild fails to build).

Comment: @crispyduck You should definitely join Tensorflow_js_EN community in telegram. This method may not work but one member of the community made another workaround

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_Gmt-q8TCpV8q7lDmO3vikHrC9r8-0jY?usp=sharing